# Infinite periodic orbits

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems

Given a billiard cycling around a polygon, reflecting off each edge perfectly with no loss of energy, we know that there exist periodic orbits in specific classes of polygons (such as equilateral triangles).  Is it possible for an orbit of arbitrarily large period, or even infinite period to exist in some polygon?

Comment: What do you mean by “infinite period”?

Comment: Think about transcendental angles. The answer is yes.

Comment: The hard problem goes in the opposite direction: is it true that every billiard has a periodic trajectory?

Comment: @RocketMan by "infinite period" I mean that after an infinite number of bounces it returns to its initial starting point and trajectory so it repeats the same infinitely long orbit again.  This may be a paradox, it is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @Grassi The usual point of view probably says "no" to both questions. Billiard is a mapping $\overline{s} = f(s)$ where $s$ and $\overline{s}$ are points on billiard's boundary. Given an initial point $s_0$ the mapping generates a sequence $\lbrace f^{n}(s_0) \rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} = \lbrace s_0, f(s_0), f(f(s_0)), \dots \rbrace$. If at some index $i$ of this sequence you have $s_{i+n} = s_{i}$, the sequence starts to repeat itself and just consists of this length-$n$ repeated block.